# Is there a way in NMAKE to escape backslashes in the macro definition option in CL?

Tags: nmake

If I have the following C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf(MACRO);
}
```

And Makefile:

```
MYPATH=$(HOMEDRIVE)$(HOMEPATH)\foobar
main.exe: main.c
    CL /DMACRO=\"$(MYPATH)\" main.c
```

It fails because the program expands to:

```
int main()
{
    printf("C:\Users\me\foobar");
}
```

And the backslashes are taken as escape chars by the C compiler.

Is there any way for NMAKE to run:

```
CL /DMACRO=\"C:\\Users\\me\\foobar\\\" main.c
```

Comment: Does the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the double-backslashes in NMAKE via macro substitution:

```
MYPATH=$(HOMEDRIVE)$(HOMEPATH)\foobar
MYPATH2=$(MYPATH:\=\\) # double any back-slashes
main.exe: main.c
    CL /DMACRO=\"$(MYPATH2)\" main.c
```

See e.g. "Substitution Within Macros" (page 36) in  https://www.scribd.com/document/19344397/Managing-Projects-With-NMAKE.

(You may also want to add a trailing back-slash to `foobar`.)

Comment: **Edit:** To add a trailing backslash, you will need to either add two backslashes to the end of the definition of `MYPATH`, or _four_ to the end of the definition of `MYPATH2`.